# Notes/Domino : Howe to modify hint server in DB/View/Document link

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

How to modify hint server string in Document links?
Many DBs will be moved to a new server and I'd like to update hint server strings in many DBs. How can I do this?

Comment: The NotesRichTextDocLink class has a Serverhint (as String) property.  I don't know of a way to update that en masse without writing an agent yourself.

Comment: If you're going to write code, The Midas rich text API from Genii Software would probably be a better choice than the native LotusScript NotesRichText classes. It's not free, but I'm pretty sure that fixing server hints was one of the original features, and knowing Ben there's probably extremely well tested sample code provided to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I understand I need to modify the codes programatically.